# Separating Data in the same excel column

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a column of data with multiple value types in it. I am trying to separate out out each value type into a separate column. Below an example of the data:

```
6 - Cutler, Jay (Ovr: 83)
22 - Forte, Matt (Ovr: 88)
86 - Miller, Zach (Ovr: 80)
```

I tried to separate the data by a) going to data and clicking text to columns; however, the "Ovr: 80" portion of the data does not separate "Ovr" from 80. I also tried b) to convert to .csv file, but again was unable to separate "Ovr" from "80". Is there a formula I can use to separate this portion of the data from the rest?

I would like the data to be separated into different columns as show below:

```
6 | Cutler, | Jay | Ovr | 83
22 | Forte | Matt | Ovr | 88
86 | Miller | Zach | Ovr | 80
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: looking at your data you could try something really simple which might work if the data is always like this, replace - , ( ) : characters with nothing and then finally replace a double space with a single space, then you end up with a perfect space delimited set of data :), i guess you could setup a formula to do that, i personally would use vba and either do the same above using vba or use RegEx which would be a safer option as its very versatile with changes within the data

Comment: Why is the comma after Cutler preserved and the comma after Forte and Miller dropped ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I would take an educated guess that was a typo

Comment: When you do text to columns from the ribbon, after selecting delimited, you should see a list of delimiters you can use.  I would place a check mark beside space, coma, and Other I would either choose - , (, or ).  I would also place a check in the box "Treat consecutive delimiters as one"  You can then delete the column of - if you did not choose it for a delimiter, and then repeat the process for either (Over: and choose "(" as the other delimiter.  Or if may choose to repeat the process on 80) column and choose ")" as your other delimiter.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent yes that was a typo, thanks Forward Ed

Comment: @ForwardEd that worked! I first separated the columns using the space, comma, and other. In other I started with my value as "(",  then ")", then selected the row Ovr: 80 and used ":". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this macro to place results in the cells to the right of the selected cells:

```
Option Explicit

Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, ary
    Dim i As Long, a
    For Each r In Selection
        s = r.Value
        If s <> "" Then
            s = Replace(Replace(s, "-", " "), ",", " ")
            s = Replace(Replace(s, "(", " "), ")", " ")
            s = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(s, ":", " "))
            ary = Split(s, " ")
            i = 1
            For Each a In ary
                r.Offset(0, i).Value = a
                i = i + 1
            Next a
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using the method above your could do something like this...

first clean the text so its more manageable, using this formula and copying in a column you can clean it so it become a space delimited set

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"- ",""),",",""),"(",""),")",""),":","")
```

from there just copy the values the formula give you to a new sheet maybe and then use 'Text To Columns to get it split into columns.

Answer (score 0):

For the record I do not recommend this method if you are willing to do the text to column option.

Functions used for this solution are:

- [LEFT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c)
- [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628)
- [MID function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MID-MIDB-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028)

for your first column of text use the following:

```
=left(A1,find(" ",A1))*1
```

That will pull out the first number presuming you do not have any leading spaces.  The *1 converts from text to a number.

for your second column of last times use the following:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+2,FIND(",",A1)-(FIND("-",A1)+2))
```

Provided you have a coma and a dash as indicated in your example data you will not get an error and it should pull the last name without the coma.

For your third column of first names follow the same general technique as last names with the following,

```
=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+2,FIND("(",A1)-2-(FIND(",",A1)+2)+1)
```

Follow the similar pattern to get you over column

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(":",A1)-1-(FIND("(",A1)+1)+1)
```

and finally to get your age column use this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+2,FIND(")",A1)-1-(FIND(":",A1)+2)+1)
```

copy the above formulas down as far as you need to go.